# How to show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)2^n}$ converges uniformly in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The ratio test gives me $1/2$, which means that it converges, but does it so for all $\Bbb R$? How do I prove that it converges specifically in the interval $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct problem statement? As is, you can just pull the function out and sum the geometric series since $\frac x{1+x^2}$ doesn't depend on $n$.

Comment: @user8128 Your statement does not imply Uniform Convergence.

Comment: @Dr.MV Interesting. Is there an example of a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is well-defined everywhere and an absolutely convergent sequence $a_n$ such that $g_N(x) = \sum^N_{n=1} f(x)a_n$ does not converge uniformly to $\left( \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n \right) f(x)$ ?

Comment: Even simpler.  The sequence $x/n$ converges to $0$ pointwise for every $x$.  But take $\epsilon =1$.  For all $N$ and for $x=n$ and $n=N+1$, $|x/n|\ge 1=\epsilon $.  This negates the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) we have

$$\left|\frac{x}{(1+x^2)\,2^n}\right|\le \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Inasmuch as $\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac12$ converges, the [Weierstrass M-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test#Statement) guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)\,2^n}$ converges uniformly.

And we are done!

Comment: That's great! Thanks!
One further question. Could you do the same with $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)2^n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{x})2^n}$$

Using AM-GM inequality :

$$x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2 \implies \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}} \le \frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{x})2^n} \le \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2^n}= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Hence :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^2)2^n} \le \frac{1}{2}$$

So, it absolutely converges $\forall ~ x >0 .$